# ImportError: C extension: DLL load failed: %1 win32

Tags: python, pandas

I try to install `numpy+mkl` and `scipy` and after that I got an error

```
ImportError: C extension: DLL load failed: %1 Win32. not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first.
```

I changed version of `python` and `libs`, but this error doesn't disappear.
How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [WinPython](https://winpython.github.io/) if you are running in Windows. It is a free open-source portable distribution of the Python programming language for Windows 7/8/10. The thing is that after you install (actually is just extract), you would have all of those three package installed by default<sup>[[1]](https://github.com/winpython/winpython/blob/master/changelogs/WinPython-3.4.4.2.md)</sup>.